# pexpect output not showing

Tags: python, pexpect

Our simple pexpect script has this:

```
import pexpect
import sys

test = pexpect.spawn('ftp www.today.com')
test.logfile = sys.stdout
test.expect('Name.*')
```

However, on the shell the script was invoked, there's no output shown.
Instead it seems to hang but we could see the process ftp ... is spawned.

How to have the output shown on the shell the script is invoked ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Should this line:

```
test = pexpect.spawn('ftp www.today.com')
```

not be:

```
test = pexpect.spawn('ftp ftp.today.com')
```

because normally if you want `ftp`, you'll have to use `ftp.something.com`.

Comment: This answer isn't relevant to the question. FTP servers can operate on any hostname, not just ones starting with the letters ftp

Comment: @DanielLawson: `ftp` vs. `www` is the core issue here. `ftp www.today.com` leads to a timeout, while `ftp ftp.today.com` shows `ftp>` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

test.logfile will only contain the output of the command, the command line itself is not logged in the logfile attribute.

So as long as the command is spawned and that there is no output, nothing will be displayed in the shell when invoking your script. 
There will be a display when for example the ftp connection timout has been reached.

Comment: [`test.logfile` contains **both** input and output](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `logfile_read`. Here is the code:

```
import pexpect
import sys
test = pexpect.spawn('ftp www.today.com')
test.logfile_read = sys.stdout
test.expect('Name.*')
```

Comment: `.logfile_read` shows **less** output (it does not include `_send`) than `.logfile` shown in the question

Comment: From the question it seems like the output was needed to know  if the program is invoked then where it is stuck. So in this case, `_read` will help.I tried `.logfile` but did not see any output as mentioned in the question the script was stuck

Comment: [`test.logfile` contains **both** input and output](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class). If you see nothing with `.logfile`; you won't see anything with `.logfile_read` too